# SQlite3 fetching data in order with a paramter

Tags: python, sqlite

i am using sqlite3 to store data about a maths test and then retrieving it, there are 3 classes they can be in 1,2,3 they then get a score and it stores their name, score, class, and some other unimportant stuff.
i need to retrieve the data in order of score but only for the appropriate class.

```
def sortHighest():#define function
    con = lite.connect('scores.db')#connect to database
    con.text_factory = str #remove "u" before result
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT name, highest FROM scores ORDER BY highest DESC")#ordering data
    data = cur.fetchall()#fetching data
    con.commit()#using data
    print "|name|Best Score|"#how to print data
    for row in data:#print each piece
        print row
    print "---------------------------------------"
    menu()#back to menu
```

the table is called scores the database is scores.db. 
i need to change this bit:

```
cur.execute("SELECT name, highest FROM scores ORDER BY highest DESC")#ordering data
```

to only show ones in the asked class ie class 1.

Many thanks

EDIT: an extension; is there anyway to use my "whichclass" variable from python as the "...WHERE class=???..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the where condition in you select request :

```
cur.execute("SELECT name, highest FROM scores WHERE class=1 ORDER BY highest DESC")
```

You can construct the string by concatenation to dynamically use your variable "whichclass" :

```
cur.execute("SELECT name, highest FROM scores WHERE class="+str(whichclass)+" ORDER BY highest DESC")
```